# 0x Swap API Is there a recommended approach for handling these error responses uniformly?

Tags: 0x, api

Subject: Assistance Request for 0x Integration

Description:

Hello 0x Support Team,

I hope this message finds you well. I am currently in the process of integrating the 0x API into my project, and I've encountered some challenges related to handling error responses and understanding certain aspects of the API. I'm reaching out to request your assistance and guidance on these matters.

Problem Description:

Handling Error Responses: During my integration, I have come across various error responses, each with its own structure and content. For example:

```
{"code": 105, "reason": "Error", "message": "Dai/insufficient-balance"}
{"code": 100, "reason": "Validation Failed", "validationErrors": [{"field": "sellAmount", "code": 1004, "reason": "INSUFFICIENT_ASSET_LIQUIDITY", "description": "We are not able to fulfill an order for this token pair at the requested amount due to a lack of liquidity"}]}

{"message": "no Route matched with those values"}
```

Managing these diverse error responses consistently in my integration has proven challenging. Is there a recommended approach for handling these error responses uniformly?

Error Response Documentation: I have been searching for comprehensive documentation that explains how to handle different error scenarios and identify them based on the response content. Could you provide guidance or point me to relevant documentation on how to effectively handle error responses from the 0x API?

Common Error Response Structure: It would be immensely helpful if 0x could provide a standardized error response structure that we can anticipate in error scenarios. Having a common structure would greatly simplify error handling within our integration.

Request for Assistance:

I kindly request your support and guidance in addressing these challenges. Your expertise and insights would be invaluable in ensuring a smooth and robust integration of the 0x API into our project.

Additional Information:

Programming Language: [Specify the programming language you're using]
Integration Environment: [Provide details of your integration environment, if relevant]
Thank you for your assistance:

I appreciate your prompt attention to this matter. Your support is crucial to the success of our integration with the 0x API. Please don't hesitate to reach out if you require any further information from my end.

Looking forward to your guidance and recommendations.

Best regards

Comment: Hey, you might get more answers if you reformat the question in a way that more concisely expresses your issue.